# как использовать `LIKE` и `NOT LIKE` вместе. SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Как вытащить данные используя Like и Not Like вместе? или может ли другие оптимальные пути для поиска слов?

Есть таблица Items:

1. Купить кабель
2. Установить кабель

Например так(но тут неправильно, выдаёт оба):

`SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Description like '%кабель%' AND Description NOT Like'%установка%'`

Result:

1. Купить кабель

Буду рад если оставите ещё полезные ссылки для изучение)))

Comment: Тут неправильно потому что `Description NOT Like'%установка%'` такое уловие и выполняется, поменяйте на `Description NOT Like'%установ%'` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @NickProskuryako, выводить оба :|

Comment: А COLLATION случайно не регистрозависимый?

Comment: Посмотрите еще в сторону полнотекстового поиска - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Akina,  не знаю, вроде нет)